# pyinstaller .exe Gmail and Googledrive not working

Tags: python

I made just simple calculator for my colleagues from python and pyinstaller.
Problem is I can't share it through gmail and google drive with other people since there is some kind of security issue.

I tried to --key as well but not working either.

pyinstaller calculator.py --key keykey5232 -i icon.ico --onefile

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "some kind of security issue"?

Comment: I can't send email whenever I tried to attached this fille.